# Is there a way to unimport or hide the base libs?

Tags: coq

Is there a way to unimport or hide the base libs in coq?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid including the standard library by passing `-nois` to `coqtop` or `coqc`.

It is also possible to create a different initial state (which you can pass to `-is`. [This](https://github.com/tomprince/coq-ext-lib/blob/trunk/Makefile) has some code to do that (while having nothing else interesting in it).